# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: self.senderDisplayName != nil'

Tags: swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have upgraded my app to Swift 3, and the latest version of `JSQMessagesViewController`. However, there is a new error appearing outlined as:

```
2016-11-02 23:02:29.066710 App[734:263241] *** Assertion failure in -[App.IndividualChatController viewWillAppear:], /Users/Desktop/iOS_Projects/App/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m:277
2016-11-02 23:02:29.068105 App[734:263241] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: self.senderDisplayName != nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I understand the error of `self.senderDisplayName != nil`, but nowhere did I ever need to assign senderDisplayName previously.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set your `self.senderDisplayName = CurrentUser`
The sender display name is used for when you are creating a new message. This is the name for the current user. So you can call this in the view did load if you would like it just has to be set to something. Hope that helps.

Comment: When was this requirement added to the library?

Comment: I don't know necessarily I would assume around version 7